# SwiftUI MVVM simple concept confusion - advice needed

Tags: mvvm, swiftui

I'm struggling with some basic MVVM concepts in SwiftUI. I appreciate this is probably a simple question but my brain is frazzled I can't figure it out.

Here's my models/views/viewmodels etc.

```
import Foundation

struct Challenges {
    var all: [Challenge]
    
    init() {
        all = []
    }
}

struct Challenge: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    private(set) var id = UUID()
    
    private(set) var name: String
    private(set) var description: String
    private(set) var gpxFile: String

    private(set) var travelledDistanceMetres: Double = 0
    
    init(name: String, description: String, gpxFile: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.gpxFile = gpxFile
    }

    mutating func addDistance(_ distance: Double) {
        travelledDistanceMetres += distance
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ActivityChallengesApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ChallengesView()
                .environmentObject(ChallengesViewModel())
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

class ChallengesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var challenges: Challenges
    
    init() {
        challenges = Challenges()
        challenges.all = DefaultChallenges.ALL
    }
    
    func addDistance(_ distance: Double, to challenge: Challenge) {
        challenges.all[challenge].addDistance(distance)
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct ChallengesView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var challengesViewModel: ChallengesViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(challengesViewModel.challenges.all) { challenge in
                    NavigationLink {
                        ChallengeView(challenge)
                            .environmentObject(challengesViewModel)
                    } label: {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(challenge.name)
                            Text("\(challenge.travelledDistanceMetres)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Challenges")
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct ChallengeView: View {
    var challenge: Challenge
    
    @EnvironmentObject var challengesViewModel: ChallengesViewModel
    
    init(_ challenge: Challenge) {
        self.challenge = challenge
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(challenge.name)
            Text("\(challenge.travelledDistanceMetres)")
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            handleTap()
        }
    }
    
    func handleTap() {
        challengesViewModel.addDistance(40, to: challenge)
    }
}
```

I understand the concepts but I'm confused as to what the ViewModel should be.

I feel like this is overkill, i.e. sending a model object to the view and the view model as an environment object.  With this set up, I call the `addDistance()` function in the view model from within the view to make changes to the model.

```
ChallengeView(challenge)
   .environmentObject(challengesViewModel)
```

Is it better to have a view model for the collection or one view model per model object?

Comment: No view models in SwiftUI. You have to learn about the `View` data struct and @State and @Binding property wrappers which give them reference type semantics like view model objects used in UIKit have.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest version I could come up with.
I don't really understand the need for the challenges.all ? So I took it out.

I have

- a struct for the single `challenge`
- an observable class which is publishing the `challenges` array
- instantiate this once with `@StateObject` and pass it down as you did

btw: You don't need explicit initializers for structs

this is it:

```
@main
struct ActivityChallengesApp: App {
    
    // here you create your model once
    @StateObject var challenges = ChallengesModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ChallengesView()
                .environmentObject(challenges)
        }
    }
}

struct Challenge: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var description: String
    var gpxFile: String
    var travelledDistanceMetres: Double = 0
        
    mutating func addDistance(_ distance: Double) {
        travelledDistanceMetres += distance
    }
}


class ChallengesModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var challenges: [Challenge]
    
    init() {
        // Test data
        challenges = [
            Challenge(name: "Challenge One", description: "?", gpxFile: ""),
            Challenge(name: "Challenge Two", description: "?", gpxFile: ""),
            Challenge(name: "Last Challenge", description: "?", gpxFile: "")
        ]
    }
    
    func addDistance(_ distance: Double, to challenge: Challenge) {
        // find the challenge and update it
        if let i = challenges.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == challenge.id}) {
            challenges[i].addDistance(distance)
        }
    }
}

struct ChallengesView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var challengesModel: ChallengesModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(challengesModel.challenges) { challenge in
                    NavigationLink {
                        ChallengeView(challenge: challenge)
                            .environmentObject(challengesModel)
                    } label: {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(challenge.name)
                            Text("\(challenge.travelledDistanceMetres)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Challenges")
        }
    }
}


struct ChallengeView: View {
    
    var challenge: Challenge
    
    @EnvironmentObject var challengesModel: ChallengesModel
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(challenge.name)
            Text("\(challenge.travelledDistanceMetres)")
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            handleTap()
        }
    }
    
    func handleTap() {
        challengesModel.addDistance(40, to: challenge)
    }
}
```